# net::ERR_Connection_Refused when setting up AWS Web App

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, pm2

I am trying to set up an AWS Web Application. I have gotten everything pretty much working except that my backend. Whenever I launch the application I make API calls to my backend to get a list of products and such; however, I keep getting this "net::ERR_Connection_Refused."[snip of console error when loading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxpwu.png)

I have looked at the nginx logs and I don't believe the issue is there. I thought that it might be an issue with pm2 hosting the express server, but I have gotten it to work for a short period of time. After I changed from http to https it stopped working, but I'm not even sure if that is the issue. I thought it might also be a CORS issue, but I tested that with test.cors.org and it said it was fine. Any help would be much appreciated! [nginx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyxUL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I make api calls to my backend to get a list of products and such

Your frontend runs in a **web browser** and is trying to call a backend on **localhost**. If the backend is on AWS, this will not work, as localhost is not routable over the internet.

You have to setup your instance to use regular domain, e.g. `myapp.com` and setup proper SSL certification for it to use `https`.